# Сравнение строк в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Проверяю ответ от сервера, откуда приходит строка `surname` в переменную `data`. 
В итоге имею очень странную картину:

```
console.log(typeof(data)) // string
console.log(data) // surname

var f = (data === "surname");
console.log(f) // false;
```

Спасайте! Как найти ошибку?

Comment: Как вариант получить ваш результат – объявить `var data = "surnаme";` – тут буква "а" – кириллическая. А в проверках у вас всё латиницей.

Comment: Пробела в строке, которая приходит с сервера, нет?

Comment: этот вариант уже проверил и все равно так

Comment: @Sapphiron, спасибо огромное))

Comment: Посмотрите посимвольно, из чего состоит строка: `console.log( data.split("").reduce(function(p,c){p.push( c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)); return p;}, []).join(':'));` – выведет 16-ричные коды каждого из символов строки через двоеточие: `73:75:72:6e:61:6d:65`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможен пробел в строке. Если не всегда известно, как именно могут прийти данные (например, программно достаются откуда-то), можно обрезать пробелы с помощью `str.trim()`.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что не упомянут (не использован) метод [localeCompare](http://code.mu/javascript/string/localeCompare.html) (подробнее - [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)) либо универсальный [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Как эти методы помогут с проблемой в вопросе?

Answer (score -3):

У вас тут строгое сравнение (`===`):

```
data === surname
```

А надо нестрогое (`==`):

```
data == surname
```

Comment: Лучше вообще не использовать нестрогое сравнение